# Spammer in objective-c/iphone

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

Consider:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614029

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609151

[applicationWillTerminate normal exit vs ad exit iPhone question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604990)

These have all showed up in the past 24 hours, they all have the *exact same wording* (they are copy and pastes of each other), and the poster ("[Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194772/charles)", "[Charlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/194820/charlie)", "[unknown (google)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/195375/unknown-google)") is responding with answers such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604990#1608750

Comment: Looks like they ran out of how to rename Charles.

Comment: Chaz and Chuck are good ones too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK; duplicate questions deleted; comment added; all 3 user accounts confirmed for identity (via private data), and the two unregistered accounts merged into the registered account.

That do?

Comment: Amazing how quick we get at doing this with practise. And the right tools :)

Comment: And the community to point the problems out in the first place :)

Answer (score 2):

Since there isn't much the community can do about this, I would suggest flagging each question for moderator attention. Explain in each flag what you suspect is happening. There's little reason to post this kind of stuff here.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  Will do so in the future.  =)

Answer (score 1):

Flag these as spam by clicking on the flag link and select Spam. They are listed in the moderator tools as spam flagged questions and answers and if more then 5 users flag it as spam it is automatically deleted. The diamond moderators also check the list frequently and if required will intervene. If it is reoccurring flag at least one entry for moderator attention and the diamond moderators will intervene and destroy the relevant accounts.

The same process applies to offensive posts.